# Setting a menu link to open a pop-up

Tags: javascript, links, radio

I want to set an menu item to work exact like the following link

```
<a onclick="window.open('/projects/aio-radio/demo/', 'aio_radio_player', 'width=720, height=355'); return false;" href="#" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i> Radio Player </a>
```

There's only basic features like adding a class and open on a new window on wordpress menu options.

Comment: Adding the `onclick` attribute with JS after the page has loaded would be one approach.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute